# Use output from GitHub Actions container image build to feed tag value

Tags: github, github-actions

#### Synopsis

My overarching objective is to automate the build and publish of a container image to the GitHub Packages registry (and/or DockerHub). I have already set up a project that accomplishes this, however there's a "gotcha."

I want to use *output* from the container image build process to update the tag that's assigned to the container image.

For example:

```
ghcr.io/pcgeek86/aws-powershell:<versionNumber>
```

#### The Caveat

Unfortunately, the GitHub Action for Docker does a build and a push simultaneously. Hence, I am unable to capture the output from the container image build, parse the version number, and then update the environment variable containing the new tag value.

#### Question

Is there a way to separate the container 1) build and 2) push into separate steps, so that I can capture the build output and use that to modify the container image tag, before it's pushed up to the GitHub Packages registry?

Comment: If you're using https://github.com/docker/build-push-action you can set `push: false` to build but not push. What _output_ from the container are you planning to use, though, isn't the version an _input_ to that process?

Comment: The module version is unknown until the build runs. The URL that AWS provides to download the "latest" version of the PowerShell module doesn't contain the exact version number intentionally. If you want to see the code: https://github.com/pcgeek86/aws-powershell-container

Comment: So I can set `push: false` and then how do I capture and parse the output from the build? That's the next part I need to figure out.

Comment: Is the idea that you need the previous tags to update the push? Or are you just doing some steps in the dockerfile that do tag manipulation? It sounds like you need to look into https://github.com/docker/metadata-action which is provided by the github actions docs when publishing docker files https://docs.github.com/en/actions/guides/publishing-docker-images#publishing-images-to-github-packages

Comment: @EdwardRomero I need to capture some output from the build script and use that as the tag for the container image.